# Error 500 using apache 2.4: django ImportError: No module named 'myproject'

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am using Apache 2.4 with python 3.4 and corresponding version of mod_wsgi on a windows 2012 R2 server machine. All 64 bits. Right now after starting apache, I have this problem:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

So when going through the error log, I found those relevant lines (logging in debug mode):

```
The 'Apache2.4' service is restarting.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.561983 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7756:tid 528] AH00424: Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the server.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.561983 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 10092:tid 456] child.c(1157): AH00357: Child: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.561983 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 10092:tid 1000] child.c(735): AH00348: Child: Accept thread exiting.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.561983 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 10092:tid 996] child.c(735): AH00348: Child: Accept thread exiting.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.577609 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7756:tid 528] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.4.2.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.577609 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7756:tid 528] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.4.3.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.577609 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7756:tid 528] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.4.12 Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.577609 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7756:tid 528] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC10 Server built: Jul  9 2016 11:59:00
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.577609 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7756:tid 528] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.577609 2016] [core:debug] [pid 7756:tid 528] log.c(1543): AH02639: Using SO_REUSEPORT: no (0)
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.577609 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7756:tid 528] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 10576
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.577609 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 7756:tid 528] mpm_winnt.c(429): AH00402: Parent: Sent the scoreboard to the child
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.905752 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 10576:tid 456] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.4.2.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.905752 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 10576:tid 456] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.4.3.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.905752 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 10576:tid 456] mpm_winnt.c(1718): AH00453: Child process is running
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.905752 2016] [wsgi:info] [pid 10576:tid 456] mod_wsgi (pid=10576): Initializing Python.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.952607 2016] [wsgi:info] [pid 10576:tid 456] mod_wsgi (pid=10576): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.952607 2016] [wsgi:info] [pid 10576:tid 456] mod_wsgi (pid=10576): Adding '\xe2\x80\x9cC:/Apache24/htdocs/EquipmentCalibration\xe2\x80\x9d' to path.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.952607 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 10576:tid 456] mpm_winnt.c(343): AH00391: Child: Retrieved our scoreboard from the parent.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.952607 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 10576:tid 456] mpm_winnt.c(465): AH00403: Child: Waiting for data for listening socket 0.0.0.0:8090
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.952607 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 7756:tid 528] mpm_winnt.c(512): AH00408: Parent: Duplicating socket 500 (0.0.0.0:8090) and sending it to child process 10576
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.952607 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 7756:tid 528] mpm_winnt.c(512): AH00408: Parent: Duplicating socket 540 ([::]:8090) and sending it to child process 10576
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.952607 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 7756:tid 528] mpm_winnt.c(531): AH00411: Parent: Sent 2 listeners to child 10576
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.952607 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 10576:tid 456] mpm_winnt.c(465): AH00403: Child: Waiting for data for listening socket [::]:8090
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:08.952607 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 10576:tid 456] mpm_winnt.c(490): AH00407: Child: retrieved 2 listeners from parent
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:09.577635 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 10092:tid 456] child.c(1214): AH00359: Child: Released the start mutex
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:09.577635 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 10576:tid 456] child.c(1020): AH00352: Child: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:09.577635 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 10092:tid 456] child.c(1226): AH00361: Child: 64 threads blocked on the completion port
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:09.577635 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10576:tid 456] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:09.577635 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 10576:tid 872] child.c(399): AH00334: Child: Accept thread listening on 0.0.0.0:8090 using AcceptFilter data
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:09.577635 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 10576:tid 876] child.c(399): AH00334: Child: Accept thread listening on [::]:8090 using AcceptFilter data
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:10.581491 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10092:tid 456] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:10.581491 2016] [wsgi:info] [pid 10092:tid 456] mod_wsgi (pid=10092): Destroying interpreters.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:10.581491 2016] [wsgi:info] [pid 10092:tid 456] mod_wsgi (pid=10092): Destroy interpreter 'PCTEST-IIS.pctestlab.com:8090|'.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:10.581491 2016] [wsgi:info] [pid 10092:tid 456] mod_wsgi (pid=10092): End interpreter 'PCTEST-IIS.pctestlab.com:8090|'.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:10.612772 2016] [wsgi:info] [pid 10092:tid 456] mod_wsgi (pid=10092): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:10.644022 2016] [wsgi:info] [pid 10092:tid 456] mod_wsgi (pid=10092): Terminating Python.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:10.659650 2016] [wsgi:info] [pid 10092:tid 456] mod_wsgi (pid=10092): Python has shutdown.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:10.659650 2016] [mpm_winnt:debug] [pid 10092:tid 456] mpm_winnt.c(1723): AH00454: Child process is exiting
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:13.971571 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10576:tid 1116] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client ::1:61169] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:13.971571 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10576:tid 1116] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client ::1:61169] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:13.971571 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10576:tid 1116] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client ::1:61169] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:13.971571 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10576:tid 1116] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client ::1:61169] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.019608 2016] [wsgi:info] [pid 10576:tid 1116] mod_wsgi (pid=10576): Create interpreter 'PCTEST-IIS.pctestlab.com:8090|'.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.050609 2016] [wsgi:info] [pid 10576:tid 1116] mod_wsgi (pid=10576): Adding '\xe2\x80\x9cC:/Apache24/htdocs/EquipmentCalibration\xe2\x80\x9d' to path.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.053609 2016] [wsgi:info] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169] mod_wsgi (pid=10576, process='', application='PCTEST-IIS.pctestlab.com:8090|'): Loading WSGI script 'C:/EquipmentCalibration/equipcal/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.660623 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169] mod_wsgi (pid=10576): Target WSGI script 'C:/EquipmentCalibration/equipcal/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.660623 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169] mod_wsgi (pid=10576): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/EquipmentCalibration/equipcal/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.660623 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.661628 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]   File "C:/EquipmentCalibration/equipcal/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.661628 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]     application = get_wsgi_application()\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.661628 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]   File "C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.661628 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.661628 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]   File "C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py", line 22, in setup\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.661628 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.662625 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]   File "C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.662625 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]     self._setup(name)\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.662625 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]   File "C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 41, in _setup\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.662625 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.662625 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]   File "C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 97, in __init__\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.662625 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.663602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]   File "C:\\Python34\\Lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.663602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.663602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.663602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.663602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.663602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.663602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.663602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.663602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.663602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61169] ImportError: No module named 'equipcal'\r
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.678602 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10576:tid 1116] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client ::1:61170] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.678602 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10576:tid 1116] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client ::1:61170] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.679602 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10576:tid 1116] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client ::1:61170] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.679602 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10576:tid 1116] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client ::1:61170] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.679602 2016] [wsgi:info] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170] mod_wsgi (pid=10576, process='', application='PCTEST-IIS.pctestlab.com:8090|'): Loading WSGI script 'C:/EquipmentCalibration/equipcal/wsgi.py'., referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.681602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170] mod_wsgi (pid=10576): Target WSGI script 'C:/EquipmentCalibration/equipcal/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.681602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170] mod_wsgi (pid=10576): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/EquipmentCalibration/equipcal/wsgi.py'., referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.682602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170] Traceback (most recent call last):\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.682602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]   File "C:/EquipmentCalibration/equipcal/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.682602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]     application = get_wsgi_application()\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.682602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]   File "C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.682602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.682602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]   File "C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py", line 22, in setup\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.682602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.682602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]   File "C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.682602 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]     self._setup(name)\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.683601 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]   File "C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 41, in _setup\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.683601 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.683601 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]   File "C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 97, in __init__\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.683601 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.683601 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]   File "C:\\Python34\\Lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.683601 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.683601 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.683601 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.683601 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.683601 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.683601 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.683601 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.683601 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
[Wed Oct 05 12:06:14.683601 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 10576:tid 1116] [client ::1:61170] ImportError: No module named 'equipcal'\r, referer: http://localhost:8090/calbase/static
```

Apparently it looks like the problem is this:

```
Target WSGI script 'C:/EquipmentCalibration/equipcal/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
```

and:

```
ImportError: No module named 'equipcal'\r,
```

Where equipcal is my project name.

But this seems really weird, how could wsgi not loaded as python and my proejct not recognized? Especially I tried to add project directory into wsgi. My wsgi.py looks like this:

```
"""
WSGI config for equipcal project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

import os, sys    

sys.path.append('C:\Apache24\htdocs\EquipmentCalibration\equipcal')
sys.path.append('C:\Apache24\htdocs\EquipmentCalibration')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "equipcal.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And in httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"

# Change Python path used by the server.
WSGIPythonPath “/EquipmentCalibration”

# Make calls to http://localhost/ refer to the Python/WSGI-script located at the specified location.
WSGIScriptAlias / /EquipmentCalibration/equipcal/wsgi.py

# Make calls to http://localhost/static refer to the specified folder.
Alias /static/ /EquipmentCalibration/static

Alias /media/ /EquipmentCalibration/media

<Directory /EquipmentCalibration/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /EquipmentCalibration/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /EquipmentCalibration/equipcal>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

my project is located as c:/Apache24/htdocs/EquipmentCalibration with project named equipcal.

With helps I figured out most other problem but got really stuck on this one. Could somebody please help me out?

Do I need something like a wsgi_handler.py?

Comment: Does `EquipmentCalibration` exist both as a root-level directory and as a subdirectory of `\Apache24\htdocs`?

Comment: @JohnGordon no it is only in htdocs

Comment: `WSGIScriptAlias / /EquipmentCalibration/equipcal/wsgi.py` This should be the full directory name, i.e. `/Apache24/htdocs/EquipmentCalibration/equipcal/wsgi.py`

Comment: @JohnGordon wow it worked like a charm. Thanks so much! I thought I don't need to put full path because of DocumentRoot.

Comment: You should not stick your application code under ``DocumentRoot`` in the first place because if you stuff up your configuration people can download your code. Move your project out to another directory and reference it there instead.